# Targeting specific td in a foreach MVC Razor table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that displays different things for users. The last td in each row houses an Html.ActionLink and a hidden ajax loader. When the select button is pressed I am looking to have only that rows loader gif displayed. I can show each one pretty easily when select is pressed, but I'm struggling to isolate the to the individual td and show just that ONE loader. Here's the table code:

```
<table class="table" id="tblCifSelection">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PolicyNumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PolicyTypeDescription)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EffDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpDate)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ClientName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PolicyNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PolicyTypeDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EffDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpDate)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "CompleteCIF", new { UniqPolicy = item.UniqPolicy }, new { onclick = "loadFunction();"}) |
            @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UniqPolicy })*@
            <img id="cifLoader" class="ml-2 loader" src="~/Images/ajax-loader (3).gif" />

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here's the script I'm working with.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.loader').hide();
   })

   function loadFunction() {
       $(this).closest('.loader').show();

       /* These are tests I ran to see what would work and what wouldn't */
       //$('tr').closest('td').attr(' .loader').show();
       //$('.loader').show(); //this shows all loaders. Only one that works.
       $('#tblCifSelection').closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(6) img#cifLoader').show();
       $(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(6)').show();
   }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no explicit `this` in function used in inline `onclick`. You also need to research what `closest()` does

Comment: You can do one thing, in img tag create Id as cifLoader_@item.policynumber..Then loadfunction pass policy number. Like loadfunction('@item.policynumber')..Then incide loadFunction(id){$('#policy_'+id).show()

Comment: Thank you both above. Combined I was able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the assist of the two above. I was able to work out a solution that works. The table data is the same, but I changed the a small piece ..

```
 <td>
   @Html.ActionLink("Select", "CompleteCIF", new { UniqPolicy = item.UniqPolicy }, new { @onclick = "loaderFunction(this);"}) |
   <img id="cifLoader" class="ml-2 loader" src="~/Images/ajax-loader (3).gif" />        
 </td>

   function loaderFunction(t) {
       $(t).closest('tr').find('td .loader').show();
       //$('.loader').show(); //this shows all loaders
   }
```

This works perfectly. Only shows the loader on the tr that the selected button is pressed.